# Merge single attribute type 2 table into sliced snapshots

Tags: sql, plsql, oracle10g, data-warehouse

I have a table with rows specifying the start and end dates of a single attribute such as:

```
FK  START_DATE      END_DATE        ServiceA        ServiceB        ServiceC
1   01-Jan-00       18-Feb-05       N               Y               Y
1   19-Feb-05       28-May-08       Y               Y               Y
1   28-May-08                       N               Y               Y
```

And I'd like to merge these into single rows that specifiy which services were active in each time period:

```
FK  START_DATE  END_DATE        ServiceA    ServiceB    ServiceC
1   01-Jan-00   18-Feb-05       N           Y           Y
1   19-Feb-05   27-May-08       Y           Y           Y
1   28-May-08                   N           Y           Y
```

I'm not even sure what you'd call the process, currently I've broken down the source table into a list of start and stop dates and service names and am iterating through them flipping the flags and outputting a row when change in start date or end is encountered but surely there must be a pattern or at least a name for this sort of transformation.

Comment: I think it would helpful to have accurate dates in your demo data. There is a bit of ambiguity right now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an application for analytic functions:

```
select fk, dte as fromdte,
       lead(dte) over (partition by fk order by dte) as todte,
       sum(A) over (partition by fk order by dte) as A,
       sum(B) over (patition by fk order by dte) as B,
       sum(C) over (partition by fk order by dte) as C
from ((select fk, fromd as dte,
              (case when service = 'A' then 1 else 0 end) as A,
              (case when service = 'B' then 1 else 0 end) as B,
              (case when service = 'C' then 1 else 0 end) as C
       from services
      ) union all
      (select fk, tod,
              (case when service = 'A' then -1 else 0 end) as A,
              (case when service = 'B' then -1 else 0 end) as B,
              (case when service = 'C' then -1 else 0 end) as C
       from services
      )
     ) t
```

(Query might have syntax errors -- not tested.)

The inner `union all` is assigning a "counter" value for each of the services on the given date.  (As a note, the "end date" might be off by 1, depending on how the end date is interpreted.)

The outer query does a cumulative sum.  On any given date, you have the active services.  The end date for those is the next date in the sequence.

Comment: Looks promising, I'll give it a go and get back to you.

Comment: Seems very close, Its returning two rows when two services start on the same day however, one with a zero length and one with the correct span.

Comment: Just an outer query to filter the rows with identical start and end dates and as you say an off by one fix for the end dates seems to match my test data perfectly, the lead function in particular is new to me and very cool, thank you.